# how will I make interactive login

Tags: bash, login, ftp

I'm having trouble in making script with interactive login. I have made one but it doesn't ask the login, it automatically log in when i run the script.

i just need the output like this:

```
please enter ftp server :
username :
password :
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `read` (see `help read`) - can be like this:

```
read -p "please enter ftp server : " SERVER
read -p "username : " USERNAM
IFS= read -s -p "password :" USERPSS
```

In this way, you'll have the server, username and password collected in variables, respectively, `$SERVER`, `$USERNAM` and `$USERPSS`. (Note that because of `-s`, the password will not be echoed and thanks to `IFS=`, it can contain space at the beginning.)

Keep in mind that, even though the password is not displayed when prompted, you **should not** use the `$USERPSS` variable directly in a command like `ftp "${USERNAM}:${USERPSS}@{SERVER}"`, because it will be revealed to any other user that runs `ps` (for example) on this computer. Better pass on the password directly as input to the program or (best) just let the program ask for it.

Comment: look into `expect` for examples of how to do what @rozcietrzewiacz suggested in the last paragraph.